# LLDB C++ debugging

Tags: c++, vector, stl, lldb

I am new to LLDB and I am working with various `std::vector`s in my code, however when I try to print the values of a vector or to query the size of my vector with something like `expr '(int)myVector[0]'` or `expr '(int)myVector.size()'` the debugger prints values that have nothing to do with the values I know there are in the vector.

As I'm learning to debug with command line and LLDB, I'm sure I'm missing something here, can anyone spot my error or give some advise?

**EDIT** Forgot to say that I'm under OS X Mavericks with the latest command-line tools installed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Apparently the overloaded operators like `[]` are not allowed since they are inlined, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387942/evaluating-an-expression-with-overloaded-operators-in-c-lldb) for a better explanation on that.

Moreover, I don't know why did I put single quotes for the statement I wanted to evaluate (I'm pretty sure I saw it in other place ... what do they actually mean in LLDB?) like so `expr 'printf("Hey")'`

So, taking out the quotes and using the answer in the cited question it suffices with something like

`expr (int) myVector.__begin_[0]`

to get the single value of a position in the vector.

Comment: However, one thing still remains to be solved, how to get the size of a vector?

Comment: `expr (int)myVector.size()` doesn't work? (Or using `p` instead..?)

Comment: Nope, getting the following `error: call to a function 'std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >::size() const' ('_ZNKSt3__16vectorImNS_9allocatorImEEE4sizeEv') that is not present in the target
error: 0 errors parsing expression
error: The expression could not be prepared to run in the target`

Comment: How about (untested) `expr (int) (myVector.__end_ - myVector.__begin_)`? But that might give you the size in bytes, rather than in terms of 'number of entries in the vector'

Comment: This works for getting the size (without the int cast):  `expr (myVector.__end_ - myVector.__begin_)`

Answer (score 3):

Use `p myVector` or `po myVector`. These will print out the contents of your vector (alongside the size) in a couple of different formats.

To print a single value from the vector, you can use something like `p (int)myVector[0]`.

Comment: "po" will probably work but honestly I don't see the point - a C++ vector isn't an ObjC object, and what "po" is for is specifically printing ObjC objects via their -description/-debugDescription method. Since a C++ vector is not one of those, "po" ends up being almost the same as "p"

Comment: Also, OP, showing your code would help diagnose the issue. What you're doing should be legit (assuming your vector truly contains integers that is)

Comment: `p` and `po` effectively prints the contents of the vector, but I am looking for a way to just print the single value of a position in the vector because with `p` a lot of info about the vector is printed out.

Comment: Use `p`. E.g. `p (int)myVector[0]`.

Comment: frame variable myVector[0]

Comment: In my case (Xcode 8) `po` print only the size of the vector.

Comment: in my case (CLion2017.3, osx), it doesn't work. terminal gives an error, error: Couldn't lookup symbols. however, selected answer (expr) works.